# Параметрические запросы в Oracle (Prepared Statement)

Tags: oracle, delphi, sql

Доброго времени суток.

Есть задача: синхронизировать данные с Active Directory через LDAP. Т.е. при нажатии на какую-то кнопку "Синхронизация" в программе, написанной на Delphi, обновлять все существующие и добавлять новые записи в БД Oracle.

Как я понимаю, для этого в Oracle есть операция MERGE INTO [...]. Но чтобы не грузить БД и не заставлять ее парсить 1500 запросов каждый раз, хотелось бы сделать все это с использованием подготовленных (параметрических) запросов. С этой БД я работал мало, поэтому сразу возникли вопросы. Запрос у меня получился приблизительно таким (точный сказать не могу пока, но вроде такой он и есть):

```
MERGE INTO testtable USING(
SELECT :field1_s field1, :field2_s field2, :field3_s field3, :field4_s field4 FROM dual
) data ON (data.field4 = testtable.field4)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET testtable.field1 = data.field1, testtable.field2 = data.field2, testtable.field3 = data.field3
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT VALUES(NULL, data.field1, NULL, data.field2, data.field3, NULL, data.field4)
```

На field4 в таблице testtable стоит уникальный индекс и по этому полю происходит проверка на существование данной записи в таблице.

В Delphi я использую компоненты ADO (AdoConnection, AdoQuery) для работы как с базой Oracle, так и с Active Directory. Я закрепляю за данным запросом параметры `field1_s`, `field2_s` и т.д., а затем задаю последовательно значения для параметров через `AdoQuery.Parameters.ParamByName('field1_s').Value`. Когда я вызываю процедуру AdoQuery.ExecSQL, Oracle выдает мне свою ошибку, что не все параметры были заполнены, а конкретно:

```
ORA-01008 not all variables bound
```

Уже что только не делал. Все чего добился - это другая ошибка: `ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number`, что конечно же не лучше :)

Теперь еще хотелось бы отметить, что такой же параметрический обычный INSERT отрабатывает нормально и все данные заносятся в таблицу:

```
INSERT INTO testtable VALUES(NULL, :field1_s, NULL, :field2_s, :field3_s, NULL, :field4_s)
```

А следовательно напрашивается вывод о том, что все дело в SQL-запросе. Но вот что с ним - ума не приложу! Может все дело в подзапросе SELECT, который я использую для MERGE? Например, может виновата строчка `... FROM dual`, которую я добавил только из-за того что оракл ругался на отсутствие ключевого слова FROM? Если да, то как можно переписать данный запрос, так чтобы Oracle вставил данные не из существующей таблицы, а новые данные, которые передает моя программа?

Версию Oracle на сервере точно не могу сказать, но вроде - 11. По крайней мере, клиент я использую версии 11.

Подскажите, куда мне копать? Надеюсь, объяснил все понятно. Заранее спасибо.

**UPD:**

Версия Oracle на сервере все-таки 9.2. Параметры в делфи биндю вот так:

```
q_temp.SQL.Clear;
q_temp.Close;
q_temp.SQL.Add('MERGE INTO testtable USING ' +
         '(SELECT :field1_s, :field2_s, :field3_s, :field4_s FROM dual) ' + ....
 );
q_temp.ParamCheck := true;
q_temp.Prepared := true;

for i := 0 to 10 do begin
    q_temp.Parameters.ParamByName('field1_s').Value := ldapQuery.FieldByName('field1').AsString;
      q_temp.Parameters.ParamByName('field2_s').Value := ldapQuery.FieldByName('field2').AsString;
      q_temp.Parameters.ParamByName('field3_s').Value := ldapQuery.FieldByName('field3').AsString;
      q_temp.Parameters.ParamByName('field4_s').Value := outbuf;
       ldapQuery.Next;
end;
```

Еще пробывал назначать параметрам типы ftString вручную, но это ничего не поменяло.
Сейчас попробывал сделать идентичный непараметрический SQL-запрос - все работает.

**UPD2:**

Пока, чтобы не передавать весь запрос целиком много раз, сделал хранимую процедуру и вызываю теперь ее. Но это все равно - не решение проблемы. Хотел посмотреть логи сервера, чтоб реально увидеть, что к нему приходит, да что-то не получилось. Например, утилитка Toad ругается на отсутствие таблицы dbms (права у меня рутовские). Еще пробовал [вот эту](http://www.aboves.com/products/statement_tracer_for_oracle/) вещицу, но она что-то не отображает запросы и корректно не работает. Может кто-нибудь знает какой-нибудь хороший SQL профайлер для Oracle, так чтобы можно было логи посмотреть не на сервере (туда у меня доступа нет), а на клиенте? Например, для MSSQL это [SQL Server Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms181091.aspx).

Comment: Покажите код, как биндите параметры к запросу.

Comment: Обновил ответ.

Comment: А точно ли ваш запрос к AD возвращает все данные для полей field1-3? Дебажить не пробовали?

Comment: @Drac5, конечно, дебажил. Куда же без этого :) AD все корректно возвращает. Сейчас пока все работает без параметрических запросов. Т.е. те же самые циклы, тот же самый SQL, только вместо параметров я составляю и отсылаю каждый раз новый запрос.

Comment: А может вызов q_temp.Prepare поможет решить проблему?

Comment: Увы, но у q_temp нет метода Prepare, свойство Prepared есть, а этого нет. Видимо TAdoQuery этот метод не нужен.

Answer (score 1):

ParamCheck включается до назначения SQL запроса. Попробуйте.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. ParamCheck у меня стоит по умолчанию в тру. Это я сделал на всякий случай. Кстати, Prepared тоже пробовал задавать до SQL запроса, не помогло. Щас так получилось, что придется переделать программу, чтоб она работала напрямую без участия клиента Oracle... Выбрал для этой цели Oracle Data Access Components от DevArt. Попробую еще с ним сделать то же самое. Обычный SELECT с параметром в условии WHERE, по крайней мере, на нем работает.

Comment: Я просто когда использовал в SQL запросе динамические хранимые процедуры с параметрами, была проблема что параметры оказывались пустыми. ParamCheck по умолчанию у меня был False и устанавливал я его после добавления SQL запроса. Проблема решилась, когда поставил его вперед.

Comment: Кстати помоему то что идет в блоке между SELECT и WHERE, в TQuery Delphi нельзя утановить через параметры. Могу ошибаться, у меня получалось только в условии.

Comment: Может Вы и правы. Для чистоты эксперимента, надо бы, конечно, попробовать на другой язык переписать этот код... Как что-нибудь сделаю, отпишусь.